# File in Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am building a REST API with Spring boot to allow applicant to fill out a form as below:

- fullName
- socialsecurityNumber
- birthDate
- picture(photo)
- resume(file)

I am using MSSQL Server as database, What is the best way to save a file in a Spring boot Application? I mean, the resume and the photo of the applicant. Should i save it as a blob in the database or use a link on a string field to  save the path? What is the pros and Cons of the both altenatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the data size.

In general, Saving a file on the file system is much better as compare to stroring it in the database. You should prefer to store only paths in the database and your application should use those paths to retrive the files from the file system.

There are certain problems when it come to storing files in the databases.

- You can only store file up to certain size in the database due to
  size restriction.
- Database size will grow at much faster rate so does
  the backup size.
- Restoration will also take longer time.
- Inlcusion of file data means increase in the size of query payload, making such queries slower simply because there is more data to be transferred between the application and the database.
- In term of storage cost, database is more expensive.

As per your requirement, you're going to store image & resume file (won't be a large file) so you can also opt for storing the content in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is quite depends on the application actual use case. Plus, you may use other storage services to save the images (like S3) other than file storage.

Perhaps you may consider the below items to decide a most suitable solution for your application.

1. Backup

   - If you need the backup of data and images, usually database is properly backed up, so keeping them together means you can get the backup at the same time snapshot.
   - When data and images are separately stored, you need to ensure the backup strategies of both sources meet your requirement.
2. Performance

   - Retrieving image from database or file storage can have different performance. It really depends on your selected infrastructure / service.
   - You may want to use NoSQL db, or separate the BLOB file into a separate table to tweak the perfomance of using database.
3. Housekeeping

   - Housekeeping strategy on DB / file storage requires different tool and implementation
4. Versioning

   - In case you need to keep record of each update, using DB or file storage services has quite different implementation.
5. Time Cost

   - Introducing one more external dependency (database only vs database + file) usually means you need more time to deal with exceptional scenarios
   - For supporting the application, more privileges are needed to be setup.
   - More knowledge the developers and support team need to gain

As an engineer we often faces multiple possible ways to get the work done, but the hard part is how to find a most suitable solution for the specific problem with all the constraints. Hope this help.